# How can I convert rows to columns (with custom names) after grouping?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get some row data as columns with pandas.

My original dataframe is something like the following (with a lot more columns). Most data repeats for the same employee but some info changes, like salary in this example. Employees have different number of entries (in this case employee 1 has two entries, 2 has 4, and so on).

```
employee_id    salary    other1      other2      other3
1              50000     somedata1   somedata2   somedata3
1              48000     somedata1   somedata2   somedata3
2              80000     somedata20  somedata21  somedata22
2              77000     somedata20  somedata21  somedata22
2              75000     somedata20  somedata21  somedata22
2              74000     somedata20  somedata21  somedata22
3              60000     somedata30  somedata31  somedata32
```

I'm trying to get something like the following. Salary data should span a few columns and use the last available salary for employees with fewer entries (the repeated salary values in this example).

```
employee_id    salary   prevsalary1    prevsalary2    prevsalary3    other1      other2      other3
1              50000    48000          48000          48000          somedata1   somedata2   somedata3
2              80000    77000          75000          74000          somedata20  somedata21  somedata22
3              60000    60000          60000          60000          somedata30  somedata31  somedata32
```

I tried grouping

```
df.groupby(["employee_id"])['salary'].nlargest(3).reset_index()
```

But I dont get all columns. I can't find a way to preserve the rest of columns. Do I need to merge, concatenate or something like that with the original dataframe?

Also, I get a column named "level_1". I think I could get rid of it by using `reset_index(level=1, drop=True)` but I believe this doesn't return a dataframe.

And finally, I guess if I get this grouping right, there's one more step to get the columns... maybe using `pivot` or `unstack`?

I'm starting my journey into machine learning and I keep scratching my head with this one, I hope you can help me :)

Creating dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'emp_id':[1,1,2,2,2,2,3],'salary':[50000,48000,80000,77000,75000,74000,60000]})

df['other1'] =['somedata1','somedata1','somedata20','somedata20','somedata20','somedata20','somedata30']
df['other2'] = df['other1'].apply(lambda x: x+'1')
df['other3'] = df['other1'].apply(lambda x: x+'2')
df

Out[59]:
   emp_id  salary      other1       other2       other3
0       1   50000   somedata1   somedata11   somedata12
1       1   48000   somedata1   somedata11   somedata12
2       2   80000  somedata20  somedata201  somedata202
3       2   77000  somedata20  somedata201  somedata202
4       2   75000  somedata20  somedata201  somedata202
5       2   74000  somedata20  somedata201  somedata202
6       3   60000  somedata30  somedata301  somedata302
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is using [`pd.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) with [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html):

```
g = df.groupby('employee_id')
cols = g.salary.cumcount()
out = df.pivot_table(index='employee_id', values='salary', columns=cols).ffill(1)
# Crete list of column names matching the expected output
out.columns = ['salary'] + [f'prevsalary{i}' for i in range(1,len(out.columns))]

print(out)
             salary  prevsalary1  prevsalary2  prevsalary3
employee_id                                                
1            50000.0      48000.0      48000.0      48000.0
2            80000.0      77000.0      75000.0      74000.0
3            60000.0      60000.0      60000.0      60000.0
```

Now we just need to join with the unique `other` columns from the original dataframe:

```
out = out.join(df.filter(like='other').groupby(df.employee_id).first())

print(out)

             salary    prevsalary1  prevsalary2  prevsalary3      other1  \
employee_id                                                               
1            50000.0      48000.0      48000.0      48000.0   somedata1   
2            80000.0      77000.0      75000.0      74000.0  somedata20   
3            60000.0      60000.0      60000.0      60000.0  somedata30   

                 other2      other3  
employee_id                          
1             somedata2   somedata3  
2            somedata21  somedata22  
3            somedata31  somedata32
```

Comment: Ah, so nice! Thanks man. I liked the iteration to set the column names. Also gives me insight into the use of things like filter and some functions I didn't know (like ffill or cumcount). I'd need to adjust the like='other' because actual names of columns are very different, I just faked the data to have a working example of the structure.

Answer (score -1):

pivot the table of salaries first, then merge with the non-salary data

```
# first create a copy of the dataset without the salary column
dataset_without_salaries = df.drop('salary', axis=1).drop_duplicates()
# pivot only salary column 
temp = pd.pivot_table(data=df[['salary']], index=df['employee_id'], aggfunc=list)
# expand the list
temp2 = temp.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['salary']), axis=1)
# merge the two together
final = pd.merge(temp2, dataset_without_salaries)
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work.  `pd.pivot_table(data=df['salary'], index=df.index, aggfunc=list)` returns an error `'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'`.  Maybe what you were looking for is `pd.pivot_table(data=df[['salary']], index=df.index, aggfunc=list)`?  But even then, that statement doesn't do anything useful

Comment: you're right, it's not index, it's 'employee_id'. fixed